# Storm killed Topology not getting removed from Topology list

Tags: apache-storm

I ran a storm topology on a storm cluster. Later the topology was killed. But it is not getting removed from the list of topologies. Hence I can't rerun the topology with the same name again.

Isn't there a way to remove the killed topology from the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you kill the topology you normally set a timeout for how long you want to wait for currently emitted tuples to be processed. I think the default is 30 seconds. After that the topology should be removed from the list. If you don't want to wait, you can just specify a timeout of 0 seconds, and the topology will be removed immediately.

Comment: Yes, I read this information. But the thing is it's been more than 3 days it has been killed, the topology but still shows in the list.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a bug. Try looking in the log of the supervisor(s) that's running the topology, and also the nimbus log and see if it's logging something about the topology? Which Storm version are you on?

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing
is it possible that if a 0 timeout is given, storm is unable to clean up the resources? if there are any db connections in our bolts, a 0 timeout might keep some connections open i.e holding db connections even after killing the topology

Comment: Please post a new question, the comment boxes are pretty limited in how much I can write.

Comment: @StigRohdeDøssing here u go
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55024919/resource-clean-up-after-killing-storm-topology

Answer (score 1):

When you run kill command from storm ui or command line .Storm will first deactivate the topology's spouts for the duration of the topology's message timeout to allow all messages currently being processed to finish processing. Storm will then shutdown the workers and clean up their state  .

So, maybe your topology still has message that needs to be processed .Hence the topology has not died till now .

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to kill topology is run **storm kill** from the command line. This had worked for me when one topology hung in "KILLED" state and shown in the list for hours.

```
storm kill yourToplogyName -w 5
```