# Resource clean up after killing storm topology

Tags: apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

We have a storm topology which interacts with a MariaDB database. Our Bolts implement the `IRichBolt` interface and override the lifecycle methods. We open a db connection in our `prepare` method and close it in the `cleanup` method. 
The `cleanup` method documentation says:

> Called when an IBolt is going to be shutdown. There is no guarentee that cleanup will be called, because the supervisor kill -9's worker processes on the cluster.
>   The one context where cleanup is guaranteed to be called is when a topology is killed when running Storm in local mode

And the `kill -9` command kills the process without cleaning up any resources. So we have come to this conclusion that on killing the topology it is not necessary that the `cleanup` method would be called and the db connection will be closed.

So moving forward to my question, we have a shell script for topology deployment which when executed kills the current topology with a timeout of 0 and deploys a new topology. We are facing an issue at db level that there are many connections opened which gives us the hint that previous connections were not closed. (The one opened in the previous topology).

Is our assumption correct? Will increasing the timeout clean up all the resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Increasing the topology timeout won't affect how long your worker has to clean up. When you use e.g. a 30s timeout, that just shuts off the spout and gives the rest of the topology 30 secs to finish processing.

What you want is to increase how long Storm allows a worker to spend shutting down before force killing. The https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/b07413670fa62fec077c92cb78fc711c3bda820c/storm-server/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/DaemonConfig.java#L780 option allows you to specify how long Storm will wait before sending the `kill -9`. The default is 3 seconds. You need to set this option in `storm.yaml`, setting it in the topology configuration will have no effect.

Comment: hi stig, when the `storm kill` command is executed does it call the `cleanup` method on bolts? if not how can we can clean resources like open db connections before shutting down. When we kill our topology, the `threads_connected` count does not decrease on db which makes us believe that it doesn't close connections on shutdown

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. Storm does call `cleanup` when a worker is shut down, but it also only allows the worker to spend 1 second shutting down (the shutdown hook has 1 second to run, then the runtime is killed). IMO we could make the delay here configurable https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/e0feb6cf04107029d4b24420f265495cdfbdb098/storm-client/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/daemon/worker/Worker.java#L130. Feel free to raise an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa for this. If you'd like to work on it, take a look at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md.

Comment: well then it means that during 1 second if a db connection isn't closed, it will remain open. This does not ensure completely that all resources have been cleansed

Comment: Spend couple of days until I finally found here, that this needs to be configured in `storm.yaml` and not toplogyw-wise in that config. How to know to set which config at which place?